# Will AllowAppOnlyPolicy and CreateUserClientContextForSPHost elevate user rights

Tags: provider-hosted-app, token

If one has enabled `AllowAppOnlyPolicy` and use the `CreateUserClientContextForSPHost` method will I elevate the users rights, or is this only the case when you create app only token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `AllowAppOnlyPolicy`  in app manifest alone will not guarantee that your code will be run in elevated rights. But you should generate `apponlyaccesstoken` using `TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken` and use this token in `TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken` to generate the client context. Now this context will be of elevated rights.

`CreateUserClientContextForSPHost`  will always  be run under the current user context.

Please see this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/02/23/sharepoint-2013-app-only-policy-made-easy.aspx) which explains AppOnlyPolicy.